# derivative, implicit derivation, trick

Tags: derivatives

I have the equation:

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2\frac{dy}{dx})-6x \neq0$

How do you get R? Do you use chain rule or product rule? I cant see how it is done? Or implicit derivation? What is u and v in that case?

$R=x^2y''+2xy'-6x$

The same with:

$\frac{d}{dx}(k\frac{dy}{dx})+Q \neq 0$

I cant see the trick that is done.

R=???

Comment: What does R represent?

Comment: I know differential equations, but I never saw differential inequalities.

Comment: R represent a residual, used in galerkin method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product rule:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^2 \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\right) = \frac{\text{d}x^2}{\text{d}x}\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} + x^2\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} = 2x\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} + \frac{\text{d}^2y}{\text{d}x^2} = 2xy' + x^2y''$$

And in general:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(K \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\right) + Q =  \frac{\text{d}K}{\text{d}x}\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} + K\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} + Q = K'y + Ky'' + Q$$